# python aws botocore.response.streamingbody to json

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 to acccess files from S3,
The objective is to read the files and convert it to JSON
But the issue is none of the files have any file extension (no .csv,.json etc),although the data in the file is structured like JSON

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'AKEY',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'ASAKEY',
    region_name = 'us-east-1'
)
obj = client.get_object(
    Bucket = 'bucketname',
    Key = '*filename without extension*'
)
```

`obj['Body']` returns a `<botocore.response.StreamingBody>` object

is it possible to find out the data within it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The extension does not matter. Assuming your file contains valid json, you can get it:

```
my_json = json.loads(obj['Body'].read())
```

Comment: Even better `my_json = json.load(obj['Body'])`

Answer (score 0):

The response is a dictionary object.
Response returns StreamingBody in 'Body' attribute. So here is the solution.

Find more information here.
[Boto S3 Get Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

```
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.get_object(
        Bucket='<<bucket_name_here>>',
        Key='<<file key from aws mangement console (S3 Info) >>'
    )
    jsonContent = json.loads(response['Body'].read())

    print(jsonContent)
```